# How to update contents in a second component based on websocket event received at first component?

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, angular5

I have a websocket logic written in Component A as follows.

```
    this.socketService.connect('/socket_url');
    this.statusSubscription = this.socketService.messages
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result !== 'pong') {
            // update Component B with the response obtained
        }
    });
```

I wonder how can I update Component B, whenever I receive a websocket event on the go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of a shared Service and Observable as follows.

shared-data.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService {

  public userStatusToggle: Observable<any>;
  private userStatusSubject = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
    this.userStatusToggle = this.userStatusSubject.asObservable();
  }

  notifyUserStatusChange(data) {
    this.userStatusSubject.next(data);
  }
}
```

Component A

```
.
.
.

constructor(private  sharedDataService: SharedDataService) {    
}

this.socketService.connect('/socket_url');
this.statusSubscription = this.socketService.messages
        .subscribe(result => {
            if (result !== 'pong') {
                this.sharedDataService.notifyUserStatusChange(result);
            }
        });
```

Component B

```
.
.
.
constructor(private  sharedDataService: SharedDataService) {    
}

this.sharedDataService.userStatusToggle.subscribe(userStatus => {
    // Do action with the 'userStatus' obtained
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this if the components are in parent/child relationship:

Component A(parent):

```
this.socketService.connect('/socket_url');
    this.statusSubscription = this.socketService.messages
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result !== 'pong') {
            this.componentBdata = result;
        }
    });
```

In componentA.html

```
<componenB [data]="componentBdata "> </componentB>
```

In componentB (child):

```
export class ComponentB implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input() data: string;
  private _data: string;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const data: SimpleChange = changes.data;

    if(data.previousValue ! = data.currentValue){
       this._data = data.currentValue;
       // do your change here
    }
  }

}
```